# Eye-Fi card: Where does it store data on Android?

Tags: sdhc

I'm developing an app that works in conjunction with an Eye-Fi card (Pro X2 - which I understand will work faster over a wi-fi connection to Android) Question is, Android has so many memory locactions, (internal: private to app and not user readable, "external" storage which can be the fixed internal storage or SD card)

So I'm seeking the help of Eye-Fi users to discover WHERE the device stores its data, and also if a folder is selectable by user.

For example, if I create a folder on the internal fixed memory, would an Eye-Fi user be able to set up the device to send data to that folder? Or does Eye-Fi set it's own folder that the user cannot change, and if so, where is it?

Alas, I can't test it myself at present as I have an OLD camera that uses an XD card!! (Eye-Fi being SDHC)

Answer (score 0):

According to [this article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eye-Fi) you must be able to select the local location as well as remote service (which is default setting):

> Settings of the Eye-Fi card such as wireless network access, selecting
>   upload location on local computer and configuring photo sharing sites
>   is done through software called the Eye-Fi Center which is available
>   for both Microsoft Windows and Mac OS X. Recently mobile access (in
>   beta) has been added via a browser.